# Can I see git log in table format

Tags: git

I am using git I want see git logs in table format and each column should be in different color.

format should be :

datetime  commithash    authorname  message

Comment: If you want "pretty" view of the log why don't you try some GUI client for git?

Comment: @Rafael : I am using git bash

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `git log --pretty` formatting:

```
git log --pretty=format:'%C(blue)%ai %C(yellow)%H %C(green)%an %C(red)%s'
```

See [Git log format string cheatsheet](https://devhints.io/git-log-format) for more.

Comment: Thanks for the answer